# UIActivityViewController how to convert string to print

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm using UIActivityViewController to share some text from my app. I can send the text to messages, email, copy etc but I can't send it to print.

I see UIActivityTypePrint takes a datatype of NSData. How can I create UIActivityViewController to take my string as both a string and NSData so that the view has the print option available?

```
NSString *textToShare = self.note.note;
        NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textToShare, nil];
        shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
        shareVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,  UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, nil];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it. It doesn't take NSData directly, it takes UISimpleTextPrintFormatter.

```
NSString *textToShare = self.note.note;

UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *printData = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                                         initWithText:textToShare];
NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textToShare,printData, nil];
shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
shareVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,  UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, nil];
```

Comment: I upvoted this in late 2013 because it solved the same problem for me in iOS 7. However, I find that iOS 8 does not accept a UI__PrintFormatter -- it will crash.

Comment: Works fine on iOS8 for me. I just used UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter with HTML to improve the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add another item of NSData type in the array itemsToShare

```
NSString *textToShare = self.note.note;
NSData* data = [textToShare dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textToShare,data, nil];
shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
shareVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,  UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, nil];
```

OR

use dictionary to send item

```
NSString *textToShare = self.note.note;
NSData* data = [textToShare dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:textToShare forKey:@"shareString"];
[dictionary setObject:data forKey:@"shareData"];
NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dictionary, nil];
[dictionary release];
shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
shareVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,  UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, nil];
```

Comment: thanks but neither are showing the 'print' option either on simulator or device....

Comment: I have a feeling that the print activity won't accept simply a string. I think it must be wrapped into something else?

Comment: Got it. It doesn't take NSData directly, it takes UISimpleTextPrintFormatter.